# Jest mockup function for chart.js options

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

How to mock functions which are in options of Line chart. As per my requirement I have written custom functions and attached it to onHover and animation onProgress events.

How to mock those functions and also to mock getEventAtElement?

Comment: Please provide the minimal code under test.